# find the left and right adjoints of the inclusion of integers into real numbers

Tags: category-theory

Any ordered set $S$ can be considered a category as follows:

The objects are the elements of $S$ and there is a unique morphism $ s \rightarrow s'$ IFF $s \leq s'$

for the inclusion functor $ i : Z \hookrightarrow \Re $ the ceiling $\lceil - \rceil : \Re \hookrightarrow Z $ is a left adjoint.

I want to understand why this is so.

I also need to find the right adjoint for $ i : Z \hookrightarrow \Re $

here is what I'm thinking:

For all $r \in \Re$ and $z \in Z$

Since in Integers $\lceil r \rceil \leq z$ IFF $r \leq z$ in $\Re$ therefore $\lceil - \rceil$ is a left adjoint.

I'm thinking $\lfloor - \rfloor$ is a right adjoint.

My reasoning is: 
for all integers $z \leq \lfloor r \rfloor$ IFF $z \leq \lfloor r \rfloor$ in $\Re$

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far :)

Comment: Are you considering the integers and the reals with the category structure given by the order relation?

Comment: @egreg sorry i left out the preamble to the question. I just included it now in an edit.

Comment: @Shaun I haven't tried anything as I don't know how to show I have a left/right adjoint or to find one.  I do know the definitions of each, and that is it :(

Comment: Then tell us your thoughts. You'll benefit much more that way :)

Comment: @Shaun I have put up what I have so far, hope that gets rid of my -ve vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since between two objects there is at most one morphism, there's no question about a map between hom-sets being natural.

If $i$ is the inclusion, you want to find a map $L\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that, for all $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $r\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(L(r),z)\cong\hom_{\mathbb{R}}(r,i(z))
$$
which means $L(r)\le z$ if and only if $r\le i(z)$. Such a map is indeed the ceiling function, because
$$
\lceil r\rceil\le z
$$
is equivalent to $r\le z$ for integer $z$.

So your conjecture about the right adjoint is good; and the proof is good.